# Slow response on GitHub Pages with NameCheap

Tags: domains, domain-registrar, latency

I have two domains registered with NameCheap and I'm pointing them to GitHub Pages. I noticed that when I use GitHub link (eg. http://davidmogar.github.io/ample) the connection is reasonably fast, but when I use the domain (http://ample.style) that is configured as GitHub says, the first connection is so slow.

I checked on Chrome Developers Tool and during the first connection I usually have a 1s Proxy negotiation delay. Could be this caused by NameCheap DNS servers? Are they really so slow? And, in this case, any good alternative?

Comment: Err think your confused how DNS works... Name servers have the task of resolving domain to IP, your name servers are not queried every-time someone visits your site, due to DNS propagation which will be cached by thousands of servers, some may respect your TTL some may not. Also, most ISP's nowadays cache DNS, as well as home routers. If your site is slow then its likely the server first byte on the negotiation of your domain, something you don't have control of because you host at GITHub ~ if problem don't host on github with custom domain.

Comment: PS ~ your site responses server fast on both for me. Below 400ms which more than acceptable.

Comment: Yeah, I get that. The problem is just with the first connection. I understand that GitHub can be slower that other paid hostings, but that's not a problem. The first connection is.

Comment: The first connection is referred to 'First Byte' and often that is the major difference when using cheap hosting, or free hosting. You should also note, that testing locally is unreliable because of routing, you should use multiple testing locations with multiple passes.

Comment: Regarding your last comment, in my case is 1.4s (Spain) and mostly the same in Switzerland. That is mainly for the 1s Proxy negotiation.

Comment: Nothing to do with proxy negotiation, a domain is not a proxy.

Comment: Good to know. I'm only saying that because Chrome info while trying a first connection to the site. I also compared loading times with others GitHub Pages using a custom domain (not NameCheap) and they respond in around 400s.

Comment: I don't see a problem, I've tested it using 6 different regions throughout EU and all under 1s.

Comment: It's definitely nothing to do with namecheap... when people visit your site a DNS lookup is done to the nearest major DNS server, not namecheap.... this is why when updating records at a domain it can take 1-48 hours for the rest of the world to get the new records.

Comment: The issue your describing is known as server `first byte`, this is when a lookup has completed and your browser has sent a request to the server, then the server must reply... the delay is out of your hands and totally to do with your hosting, in this case GitHub. Rather than using Chrome I recommend you use more reliable tools, useful tools that reveal more information. i.e webpagespeedtest... Also, it could be non-www issue as linked for the closure reason, I don't see a unique question, as first byte has been discussed many times on Pro Webmasters.

Comment: I'm Having the Same issue with Github Pages & Namecheap, Video mp4 which is only 14mb is taking ages to load, sometimes it loads sometimes it doesn't.. example here : https://art4coding.icu github opensource project here: https://github.com/MistaKistHur/Art4Coding-Resources  Theres only one video, one image and a few scripts such as p5.js, cloudflare etc..